# Python assignment for a phonebook

Tags: python, dictionary

This weeks lab is based on the example on pages 53,54 of the wikibook "Non-Programmers Tutorial For Python" by Josh Cogliati (2005), (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Dictionaries).

In his example, Cogliati has options for printing, adding, removing, and looking up a phone number. Change the code so that, instead of the value in the dictionary being a simple phone number, it is now a list with three values:

- phone number
- e-mail
- address web page

The key should still be simply the persons name. Adapt the menu used in the example accordingly, for example the '2. Add a Phone Number' should now read '2. Add an entry' and if selected should ask the user for the 4 items of information (name, phone, email, web). Aditionally:
Add an option (e.g. number 6 in the menu) to 'Change/Edit an existing entry'.
Add options to:

- Print just a list of the phone numbers
- Print just a list of the e-mail addresses
- Print just a list of the web addresses
- Print all of the above together

This is the assignment we were given, I understand what's given in the link and have added a bit to it, unsure as to how to go about adding in the calling upon of the email and webpage information once stored

Comment: what you have tried so far? post some code, explain the specific issue you are facing & then may be somebody might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I agree with the comment under your answer, I will still try my best to give you some guidance.

Original Code:

```
def print_menu():
    print('1. Print Phone Numbers')
    print('2. Add a Phone Number')
    print('3. Remove a Phone Number')
    print('4. Lookup a Phone Number')
    print('5. Quit')
    print()

numbers = {}
menu_choice = 0
print_menu()
while menu_choice != 5:
    menu_choice = int(input("Type in a number (1-5): "))
    if menu_choice == 1:
        print("Telephone Numbers:")
        for x in numbers.keys():
            print("Name: ", x, "\tNumber:", numbers[x])
        print()
    elif menu_choice == 2:
        print("Add Name and Number")
        name = input("Name: ")
        phone = input("Number: ")
        numbers[name] = phone
    elif menu_choice == 3:
        print("Remove Name and Number")
        name = input("Name: ")
        if name in numbers:
            del numbers[name]
        else:
            print(name, "was not found")
    elif menu_choice == 4:
        print("Lookup Number")
        name = input("Name: ")
        if name in numbers:
            print("The number is", numbers[name])
        else:
            print(name, "was not found")
    elif menu_choice != 5:
        print_menu()
```

Notice that `numbers` is equal to `{}` - this signifies that it is a "Dictionary", which stores key/value pairs. To add to a dictionary (or "dict"), you can modify it manually as such: `numbers = {'David': 18003574689}`. So, in order to access David's phone number, you would type in `numbers['David']`.

Another way to add to it is by instantiating it (which is already done for you via `numbers = {}`), and then **adding** information into to it via the shortcut formula `dictname['key'] = value`. So in this case, the shorthand can be `numbers['Laura'] = 9173162546`.

Now, to add a `list` into the mix, you could use `[]` (which is a list in python), but you would probably be better suited nesting another dict into the current one. For example, instead of `numbers = {'David': 18003574689}`, you can now have `numbers = {'David': {'phone number': 18003574689, 'e-mail': 'david2015@gmail.com', 'address web page': 'http://dave.com'}, 'Laura': [...etc...]}`.

To access these new nested dicts, what you can do is the shorthand `numbers['David']['phone number']`, which will return his #. You can then do this exact shortcode 2 more times `numbers['David']['e-mail']` & `numbers['David']['address web page']`. These three will access the associated data.

Since I believe this is the toughest part for a newcomer, I'll stop here since the rest should be easy. All you have to do is create new inputs in the correct `if` conditions. Assign the captured input data into proper variables via the `=` assignment operator (ex. `email = input('Email: ')`), and then use the rest of the info logically. I hope this helps.